# how to call a javascript function on a ng-directive element

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I'm trying to convert a javascript library (handsontable) to an angular-dart directive. I know how to call a method on a javascript object:

```
context.callMethod(r'$', ['#example'])
.callMethod('handsontable', [new JsObject.jsify(options)]);
```

but don't know how to call 'handsontable' on the element of the directive. The class looks like this for example:

```
class Spreadsheet {
  dom.Element element;

  Spreadsheet(this.element) {
   }
}
```

and I want to apply 'handsontable' on the element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*jQuery* can accept an element as parameter. So the following should work :

```dart
context.callMethod(r'$', [element])
    .callMethod('handsontable', [new JsObject.jsify(options)]);
```